# Django ORM query works on shell but time outs in Api View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have large list of ids and wanted to filter objects using those ids:

```
list_of_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]

MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_ids)[:20]
```

That query works just fine from shell, but when I try to do the same thing in API View it time outs:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class MyModelAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
        print(MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=ids)[:20])
        return Response({})
```

After I got the response with a 504 status code, I see in terminal logs what the print function did:

```
django_1       | <QuerySet [<MyModel: 231>, <MyModel: 268>, <MyModel: 269>, <MyModel: 271>, <MyModel: 272>, <MyModel: 274>, <MyModel: 275>, <MyModel: 277>, <MyModel: 280>, <MyModel: 281>, <MyModel: 282>, <MyModel: 284>, <MyModel: 285>, <MyModel: 288>, <MyModel: 289>, <MyModel: 290>, <MyModel: 291>, <MyModel: 292>, <MyModel: 294>, <MyModel: 298>]>
```

But I can't find out why do request time outs? I could not find similar problems there

(I understand that problem might be in my large list of ids, but shell executes that query without any problem)

Comment: A view has a threshold of 5 minutes. The shell has not...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem execution of query doesn't take more than 3 seconds.

Comment: could you please share the full error traceback and how are you accessing the api ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow

`nginx_1        | 2022/04/26 10:55:38 [error] 26#26: *2 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: IP, server: , request: "GET /api/v2/publications/", host: "localhost"`.

I tried to make requests from browser and postman. (both of them are timing out)

Comment: The issue must be somewhere else. Is API endpoint return anything if you delete your query?

Comment: @BartoszStasiak without query it doesn't time out and returns just 200

Comment: @Carmy John did you find any answer for this question?

Comment: @keramat unfortunately no, just decided to not filter by that large array